# Xml tag addition

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have one small Xml, i need to convert this to another xml format. i want to convert via xslt1.0.

Below is my input Xml

```
<Members>
    <Member name="1" />
    <Member name="2" />
    <Member name="3" />
    <Member name="4" />
    <Member name="5" /> 
</Members>
```

output xml for the above will be

```
<Members>
    <JoinMember>
        <Member name="1" />
        <JoinMember>
            <Member name="2" />
            <JoinMember>
                <Member name="3" />
                <JoinMember>
                    <Member name="4" />
                    <Member name="5" /> 
                </JoinMember>
            </JoinMember>
        </JoinMember>
    </JoinMember>
</Members>
```

Here the logic is the last two members has to included in a separate tag.

for e.g 
Member 5 and Member 4

```
<JoinMember>
    <Member name="4" />
    <Member name="5" /> 
</JoinMember>
```

for Member 3, Member 4 and Member 5

the output should be as below:

```
<JoinMember>
    <Member name="3" />
    <JoinMember>
        <Member name="4" />
        <Member name="5" /> 
    </JoinMember>
</JoinMember>
```

it also contains already combined member for Member 4 & 5.

only one combination has to be included for a JoinMember.

like same has to be repeated till the first member.

I need to do it via XSLT1.0.

Please help me on the output.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add more information on what you already tried and where you are actually stuck.

Comment: I can get the reverse loop, but not able to add separate tag in that. Below is my tried example. <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 <xsl:template match="Members">
  <Members>
   <xsl:for-each select=".//Member">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Members>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the stylesheet located in http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/flatfile.html#d5010e369.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="h2" match="Member[@name='2']"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Member[@name='1'][1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="h3" match="Member[@name='3']"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Member[@name='2'][1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="h4" match="Member[@name='4']"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Member[@name='3'][1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="h5" match="Member[@name='5']"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Member[@name='4'][1])"/>

    <!--   Wendell Piez algorithm -->
    <xsl:template match="Members">
        <Members>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Member[@name='1']" mode="h1"/>
        </Members>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member[@name='1']" mode="h1">
        <JoinMember>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h2',generate-id())" mode="h2"/>
        </JoinMember>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member[@name='2']" mode="h2">
        <JoinMember>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h3',generate-id())" mode="h3"/>
        </JoinMember>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member[@name='3']" mode="h3">
        <JoinMember>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h4',generate-id())" mode="h4"/>
        </JoinMember>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member[@name='4']" mode="h4">
        <JoinMember>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h5',generate-id())" mode="h5"/>
        </JoinMember>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member[@name='5']" mode="h5">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiHZ).

Answer (score 0):

I used a recursive template to cycle through the numbers, finally conditionally placing in the last pair in their own node.

```
<xsl:variable name="count"><xsl:value-of select="count(Members/*)"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="Members">
    <Members>
        <xsl:call-template name="recurse">
            <xsl:with-param name="memberNum" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </Members>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="recurse">
    <xsl:param name="memberNum"/>

    <JoinMember>
        <xsl:if test="$memberNum &lt; ($count - 1)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/Members/*[@name= $memberNum]"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="recurse">
                <xsl:with-param name="memberNum" select="$memberNum + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test = "$memberNum >= ($count - 1)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/Members/*[@name = ($count - 1) or @name = $count]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </JoinMember>
</xsl:template>
```

See it here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT7